# Unsafe swap space detected

Tags: system-installation, swap, ubiquity

So I had a Ubuntu 13.04 installation and I had encrypted my hard drive while I was doing installation. I was playing around and mistakenly deleted all the partitions, now I downloaded lUbuntu 13.10 x86 Desktop but when I am trying to install it says "Unsafe swap space detected"

[image]

I am clueless on how to fix this error.

Comment: At what point of the installation does this error message come up? Did you try completely formatting your hard disk? What comes up if press "OK"?

Comment: Nothing it just get aborted and then you need to try again. But it fails all the time. However how I can completely format my hard disk using lubuntu?

Comment: I am not sure whether lubuntu gives you the option to try it, if not, you may need to use Ubuntu(any version should work) to "Try Ubuntu" and then use gparted to delete all partitions and then try again.

Comment: I have already deleted all partitions using gparted even when i try to format disk it says "Error Formatting Disk" `Error syncronizing after initial wipe. Timed out waiting for object (udisks-error-quark,0)`

Answer (score 23):

Try to boot via "Try Ubuntu" instead of "Install Ubuntu" and run the command:

`sudo swapoff --all`

From the terminal. (ctrl+alt+t)

Then run the Install Ubuntu from the desktop. The error should stop appearing.

See also this related [Lubuntu/ubuntu bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1205397)

Comment: It works, thanks. Well, this problem is still there in 15.04. I wonder when it is going to be fixed?

Comment: Still a problem in 16.04!

Comment: Still a problem in 17.04

Comment: Still a problem in 18.04

Comment: Still a problem in 22.04

Answer (score 8):

Len's solution of running `sudo swapoff -all` is possible without booting via "Try Ubuntu".

When you get the error, use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> to get to a terminal and run the command there.

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>ALT</kbd>-<kbd>F7</kbd> to return to the graphical environment when you're done.

It worked for me.  I did so after going back to the language selection screen, but it may work from the partition manager stage. I would expect the check is only being done at the moment one attempts to change a partition.

Comment: It should be kept in mind that this requires enough RAM in the first place ;)

Comment: How do I get back into the setup menu after doing this?

Comment: Same question as @KajetanAbt, quite annoying.

Comment: If you want login and password then try `lubuntu` for username and just press enter for password.

Comment: When installing Lubuntu 16.04.1, I encountered this issue. For some reason, there was no virtual consoles available so I had to restart and select *Try* instead of *Install* in order to access a terminal device.

Comment: the command is `sudo swapoff --all`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, there's definitely something wrong with the installer (I was trying to set up 14.04 with encrypted partitions on different drives, with / on my small SSD and /home /usr /tmp /var and swap on my HDD). But I played around with it, restarted the installer/rebooted a number of times, and here's how you work around it:

Set up all your actual partitions, including your encrypted containers. I believe it necessary to include an encrypted partition for swap, so make sure to make one of suitable size for it.

Once you have them all set up, THEN, and only then pin them to actual mount points. I started with swap and then moved on to /home and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving the installer, rebooting and going through the wizard again was too much for me, so I tried this and it works. Saves time.

After getting the error message

- select any SwapPartitions and change to sth else, e.g. ex3.
- remove the crypto partition and install it again (its broken after the error and won't work). Now the installer did not complain any more
- from the installed version, start gparted and re-format the old swap partitions to swap again.

Im my case an older installation still needed the swap partition.

Answer (score -1):

It is this [Bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/1241833) That still exists in Lubuntu 14.04.2 Desktop i386 version. That's what i've tested - maybe this safe's some other people's nerves.

I got it working using the alternate-cd (14.04.1 i386) but there you need to make sure to select the "Install" method - not the "expert install" and not "install lubuntu" and when grub asks you to install to MBR say "No" because that is another bug and you will then be given the option to specify the correct device to install grub to.

Made a detailed answer specified for 14.04 now: [Link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/591548/how-to-install-lubuntu-14-04-with-encrypted-lvm-unsafe-swap-bug)

Greets

An