# Install Lubuntu 15.10 with encrypted lvm

Tags: usb, encryption, lvm

After setting up encrypted partitions on Lubuntu installation on a USB-Stick, there's no /dev/mapper/xxx I could bind to a mountpoint (edit partition/use as: / or swap or whatever)! On Ubuntu this was no problem but I don't see the trick for Lubuntu (which I strongly need because I only got an older system).

Comment: This is the guide I followed successfully on Ubuntu: http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/05/28/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-on-encrypted-mbr-partitions/

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug in the gparted section of the installation. There must be something wrong with the unencrypted swap area checker. If it jumps on (and it will do so to ruin your day), it's gonna say: 'unsecure swap area detected, aborting now'. And it will detect an unencrypted swap area, even if there really is one. So...

Solution:

- 1) Start (L)ubuntu and choose "try" instead of "install"
- 2) After
  booting up, open a terminal and enter "sudo swapoff --all"
- 3) Click "install (L)ubuntu" on the dekstop
- 4) After chosing 'something
  different' right before the partitioning of your future USB (L)ubuntu
  stick, set up your boot, encrypted root and encrypted swap partition.
  Afterwards set the mount point / for your encrypted root drive (mounted encrypted partitions under /dev/mapper) and
  set the other partition to use as swap area.
- 5) Also don't forget to choose the correct device for the bootloader in the pull down menu below.

After installation boot up the stick and you will be prompted (twice) for the password you set before, in order to boot up your full encrypted (L)Ubuntu USB system.

[Unsafe swap space detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393418/unsafe-swap-space-detected)
http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/05/28/how-to-install-ubuntu-14-04-on-encrypted-mbr-partitions/
http://linuxbsdos.com/2014/01/16/manual-full-disk-encryption-setup-guide-for-ubuntu-13-10-linux-mint-16/