# Dual Boot Ubuntu 16.04 w/ Full Disk Encryption + Win10 not encrypted (separate HDDs) Help

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, 16.04, encryption, windows-10

EDIT: Making this question a lot simpler.

Hello everyone,

I have 4 HDDs:

- 60GB SSD
- 500GB HDD - Win10 installed
- 1 TB HDD (x2)

As you can see, the 500GB HDD has Win10 installed on it. The other drives are all currently empty.

I want to install Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (or 14.04 if 16.04 just won't work), with Full Disk Encryption:

- 60GB SSD - System/OS Drive
- 1 TB HDD - /home
- 1 TB HDD - extra storage, will mount it somewhere after installation

When the computer boots, I want GRUB to load and give me the choice of booting the Encrypted Ubuntu installation, or the non-encrypted Windows installation.

During the Ubuntu installation, how do I partition my disks to make this happen? I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: First removed link:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/393418/unsafe-swap-space-detected

Second Removed Link:

I also found this:
https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/2061

Comment: Can you summarize your question in 1 or 2 sentences? Is it *"Can FDE even be done on a Dual Boot UEFI system, or does FDE require an MBR system?"* I think it can be done on EFI...

Comment: My questions are: 1) can this setup be done in a UEFI dual boot system? Or does it have to be MBR? 2)  If so, what am I doing wrong? Are the aforementioned partitioning guides correct for this type of setup? 3) am I missing something obvious or doing something wrong?

Comment: updated post with more clarified questions, apologies for the rambling lol

Comment: I have seen some installs with efi partition, /boot partition and LVM. Be sure to boot installer in UEFI mode. In your case it might just be easier to disconnect Windows drive and use auto install to Ubuntu drive. But you may have to manually recreate the Windows UEFI entry. When you disconnect a drive, it forgets its NVRAM settings. Several reboots may work, or use efibootmgr  to add a Windows entry after you plug in Windows drive.

Comment: @oldfred I was thinking of doing that, the only concern is that I can't just use the auto installation due to having /home on a separate 1TB drive. Because of this, I think I have to partition manually. So I'm wondering if I need to create a /boot partiton, or EFI, or both, on the Ubuntu installation. But I will try it again with Windows drive disconnected and see what happens...

Comment: Part of issue with two drives and UEFI, is that grub will only install to an ESP on sda. My main working install is on sda, but I do install to sdb, specify grub to install to sdb, but it overwrites my main working install's /EFI/ubuntu. I quickly learned to backup ESP.  I do copy files to ESP on sdb, but do not really use that. I always create ESP & bios_grub on every drive, just in case I want either UEFI or BIOS boot.  I would suggest you create the ESP & Boot partitions, but if not seen as sda, the sdb drive ESP will not be used.

Comment: Updated the question to make it much simpler