# Lubuntu 16.10 on Virtualbox unsafe swap space

Tags: virtualbox, lubuntu

I can't install Lubuntu 16.10 with the encryption option checked because it says unsafe swap space detected.

I'm aware of this question [Unsafe swap space detected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/393418/unsafe-swap-space-detected/394417) but my situation is slightly different because I'm installing it as a Virtualbox VM.

Here's my problem, after following the highest-voted answer, running 
`sudo swapoff --all` in the Try Lubuntu environment, and rebooting the VM, the machine won't boot, after the Virtualbox splash screen is shown, only a black screen with the cursor `_` is shown.

Additional: This problem doesn't seem to exist in Ubuntu 16.10, I've managed to set up Ubuntu VMs many times with encryption without a problem. I picked Lubuntu because I want to be running multiple VMs at once, so I need something with low RAM usage. Should I just install Ubuntu and then replace Unity with LXDE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You can try to install Lubuntu from an alternate iso file

Lubuntu's alternate iso files use the Debian installer in text mode. There are two test cases for isotesting, and I suggest that you use this one,

[Alternate Install (Encryption) in Lubuntu Alternate i386 in Yakkety Daily](http://iso.qa.ubuntu.com/qatracker/milestones/368/builds/133217/testcases/1439/results)

I think you can select the correct options with the help of the instructions of the testcase which contains both 'encrypted LVM' and 'encrypted home'. You will probably need only one of them, but the testcase tests both of them.

The same procedure works for both versions of Lubuntu: 32-bit and 64-bit.

### Alternatives to the alternate iso file

I would *not* recommend to install Ubuntu, remove Unity and install LXDE. It is difficult to 'remove enough but not too much'.

It is possible to start from the Ubuntu mini.iso or Ubuntu Server iso file and install LXDE. This is a good option, if you want a custom system with only the program packages that you need. I have done it recently, but it is more difficult than to install Lubuntu from an alternate iso file.

Comment: Thank you! using the alternate installer iso worked for me.